# is it possible to move 3Dmodels between hosts?

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

Here's a nice one for you guys:

--> I have a website THREE.js scene with a 3D object in it.

--> I have a mobile app with a scene and a QR scanner. it can use .obj files and .vrx files (special format for viro react)

**I want this mobile app to load the 3D model by scanning a QR code on the website with the THREE.js scene** (containing the model i want to show on my mobile app)

Now what i thought of is, transform the 3d model into a JSON object. Then save it temporarily to a remote host and transform the URL to the path of this 3D object to a QR code which i can scan with the phone. Then the phone will call the object from the remote server and transform it into .obj and then display it in the scene.

Does this sound like a viable solution? You think there's a better solution or other similar projects that have been done before?

The main problem is that each time this 3d model is different and it has to happen almost instantaniously for user experience.

Comment: so in the simplest terms the use case is: when user presses a button on a website, the 3d model that is displayed on that screen will now also be displayed on your phone in another app

Comment: **1)** Is the mobile app NOT based on three.js (hence the requirement for OBJ format)? **2)** I get the impression you don't have an OBJ file, and are expecting to build one on-the-fly. Just a hunch, but I don't think you're going to find an "instantaneous" way of doing this. Converting from three.js mesh to OBJ is going to take time. Uploading it to a server location is going to take time. Downloading it is going to take time. Opening it is going to take time. All of it hampered by network latency. Unless you're working with very small meshes, there is going to be _some_ lag.

Comment: 1:it's viro react which is based off native react which is based off reactJS. What it technically uses im not sure of, it seems like it uses the following component to draw the model on: https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/viroarscene 2: Yes you are correct, i was afraid so. i could try to look for another way to get the query settings that the original program used to construct the model, and somehow rebuild that query in the mobile app

Comment: Im thinking about embedding the web site into a webview within the app. And then find out if i can then move the data from the webview component to the other component.